# Need to reset just the indexes of a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, indexof

I have a `for` loop which returns an array.

Return:

```
1st loop:
arr[0]
arr[1]
arr[2]
arr[3]
```

Here the length I get is `4` (Not a problem).

Return:

```
2nd loop
arr[4]
arr[5]
arr[6]
arr[7] 
arr[8]
```

Here the length I get is `9`.

What I want here is the actual count of the indexes i.e I need it to be `5`. How can I do this. And is there a way that when I enter each loop every time it starts from `0` so that I get proper length in all the loops?

Comment: can you post the relevant code?

Comment: You need to show us the loop you are using, the condition inside it and the initialisation of your array in the first place.

Answer (score 39):

This is easily done natively using Array.filter:

```
resetArr = orgArr.filter(function(){return true;});
```

Comment: Worked perfect for me!

Comment: +1 clean solution. It works even using the same array: origArr = origArr.filter(...)

Comment: Note that this will not work for IE <= 8. You may implement this suggested polyfill to solve that problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Bit shorter version : resetArr = orgArr.filter(Boolean);

Answer (score 4):

You could just copy all the elements from the array into a new array whose indices start at zero.

E.g.

```
function startFromZero(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    var count = 0;

    for (var i in arr) {
        newArr[count++] = arr[i];
    }

    return newArr;
}

// messed up array
x = [];
x[3] = 'a';
x[4] = 'b';
x[5] = 'c';

// everything is reordered starting at zero
x = startFromZero(x);
```

Comment: i love you crazedgremlin..you made my day

Comment: You're welcome!

Just so you know, this is a bad solution to your problem -- you should probably choose a new data structure such as a linked list that will allow you to delete items without having to recreate the array each time.

Also, you should choose an answer if you have found a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 4):

Easy,

```
var filterd_array = my_array.filter(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "underscore.js" will be useful here.

The `_.compact()` function returns a copy of the array with no `undefined`.

See: http://underscorejs.org/#compact

Comment: awesome lib ; applies to arrays and also avoid removal of non empty objects.