# How to get the ordered index after changing values in an array in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dragula, ng2-dragula

I am having a list of items in an array say,

```
Design
Analysis
Testing
Development
```

Whose index would be,

```
0,1,2,3
```

Here i am using angular dragula which is used to drag and drop a list element. With the usage of dragula i am changing the position of an array say,

```
Analysis
Design
Development
Testing
```

The order is getting changed but whereas the index position is still the same like,

```
1,0,3,2
```

Here the index position is not in the order and its looking like the older index value despite of the order it looks like.
Whereas i need to have the same index position whatever change happen inside an array which means always the index position should start from `0,1,2,... so on` even there is a change in the order.

Html component that i have used,

```
    <div class="card-content">
        <div dropDirective (dropEvent)="addDropItem($event)" class="droppable" [dropHighlight]="'highlight'">
            <div [dragula]="'second-bag'">
                <app-generic-drop-box *ngFor="let item of itemsDropped; index as i" (editBtn)='editBtn($event)' (deleteBtn)='deleteBtn($event)' [genericBox]='item' class="arrow_box dropItem temp" (click)='indexOfItem(i)'> </app-generic-drop-box>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In ts file,

```
        import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
        import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
        import { ScenarioMapService } from '../scenario-map.service';

        import { DynamicFormModel } from '../dynamic-form-config/dynamic-form-model';
        import { Textbox } from '../dynamic-form-config/textbox';
        import { CONFIG } from '../../app.config';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-drop-area',
          templateUrl: './drop-area.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./drop-area.component.scss']
        })
        export class DropAreaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

        indexOfItem(i) {
        console.log(i); 
        }

    }
```

Here `console.log(i)` shows the index position if user click on a list if i change the position of an array i need to get the ordered index after the change like `0,1,2,3...` ..
Kindly help me to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the index in AngularJS array you could filter it with no action at all.

That way the indexes get set again.

`resetArr = orgArr.filter(function(){return true;});`

The array-indexes `1,0,3,2` will be `0,1,2,3` again but the data remains in place.

As a reference: [Need to reset just indexes of JavaScript array Stackoverflow Thread...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413887/need-to-reset-just-the-indexes-of-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Here i am using angular 2 and it would be much more appreciable if you help with my existing code..